# Moving WPF simple conditional from Codebehind to XAML

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a simple conditional, a textbox named tbDestinationTableName that should only allow user input when any selection is made from the the ComboBox cbConnection.  I currently do this in codeBehind.  Can some one correct the following code if this can be done in XAML?

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="cbConnection"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlConnectionList}, XPath=//ComboItem}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Key"
                  SelectedValuePath="Value"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ConnectionString,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  Margin="{StaticResource ConsistentMargins}"
                  />

<kit:WatermarkTextBox Name="tbDestinationTableName" Margin="{StaticResource ConsistentMargins}"
                  TextChanged="tbDestinationTableName_TextChanged"
                  Text="{Binding Path=DestinationTableName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                  Watermark="Destination Table"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ValidCreate}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe you can do something like this with your custom textbox

```
<kit:WatermarkTextBox>
    <kit:WatermarkTextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type kit:WatermarkTextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbConnection, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </kit:WatermarkTextBox.Style>
</kit:WatermarkTextBox>
```

If you want to use IsEnabled instead then it **should not be set in kit:WatermarkTextBox's xaml**.

Just use another Datatrigger like this:

```
   <kit:WatermarkTextBox Name="tbDestinationTableName" Margin="{StaticResource ConsistentMargins}"                     
                TextChanged="tbDestinationTableName_TextChanged"
                Text="{Binding Path=DestinationTableName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
              Watermark="Destination Table">
    <kit:WatermarkTextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type kit:WatermarkTextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbConnection, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ValidCreate}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </kit:WatermarkTextBox.Style>
</kit:WatermarkTextBox>
```

Comment: First example worked, but that DataTrigger is inside the kit:WatermarkTextBox in your second example...  Can you elaborate why you made this distinction?

Comment: i had a mistake there and i corrected it. In general a property that is defined in elements attributes can not be changed with Datatriggers. So if you want to toogle IsEnabled property instead of IsReadOnly you should not have it defined outside Style